# How to use AsmVisitorWrapper to visit an array inside an annotation and merge its content with another array

Tags: java, byte-buddy

(repository with an example of what I'm trying to do is [here](https://github.com/jplatasv/bytebuddy-and-annotations))

It's my first time using ByteBuddy and I've found myself struggling to merge the contents of two `@RequestMapping` annotations.
Something like this:

```
@Validated
@RequestMapping(
        path = "/somePrefix",
        produces = {"application/text", "application/xml"},
        consumes = {"application/text", "application/xml"},
        params = {"exampleParam1", "exampleParam2"},
        headers = {"key=val", "nokey=val"}
)
public interface ExampleInterface {

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/someEndpoint"}, method = {RequestMethod.POST}, produces = {"application/json"}, consumes = {"application/json"})
    ResponseEntity<String> someEndpointMethod(String value);

}
```

And pretending to having this:

```
public interface ExampleInterface {

    @RequestMapping(
        value = {"/somePrefix/someEndpoint"},
        method = {RequestMethod.POST},
        produces = {"application/text", ,application/xml","application/json"},
        consumes = {"application/text", "application/xml","application/json"},
        params = {"exampleParam1", "exampleParam2"},
        headers = {"key=val", "nokey=val"}
    )
    ResponseEntity<String> someEndpointMethod(String value);

}
```

I've seen that editing the values can be done replacing the value when the method annotation object is visited, for example:

```
[...]

@Override
public AnnotationVisitor visitAnnotation(String descriptor, boolean visible) {

    if (Type.getDescriptor(RequestMapping.class).equals(descriptor)) {

        return new AnnotationVisitor(Opcodes.ASM9, super.visitAnnotation(descriptor, visible)) {

            @Override
            public AnnotationVisitor visitArray(String name) {

                if ("produces".equals(name)) {

                    return new AnnotationVisitor(Opcodes.ASM9, super.visitArray(name)) {
                        @Override
                        public void visit(String name, Object value) {

                            // I'd like to receive an array as value, so I can provide one with all values merged

                            boolean tryToMerge = false;

                            if (tryToMerge) {

                                //I cannot return array with everything
                                Object[] newValue = new Object[]{value};
                                value = Arrays.copyOf(newValue, newValue.length + originalAnnotation.produces().length);
                                System.arraycopy(originalAnnotation.produces(), 0, value, newValue.length, originalAnnotation.produces().length);

                            } else {

                                //I can only replace a single value
                                value = originalAnnotation.produces()[0];

                            }

                            // How to set an array in produces?

                            super.visit(name, value);

                        }
                    };
                } else {

                    return super.visitArray(name);

                }
            }
        };

    } else {

        return super.visitAnnotation(descriptor, visible);

    }

}

[...]
```

However, I'm receiving the array values one per one via `visit()` and I cannot just return an array with the two values I want to merge (`["application/text", "application/xml"]`) because it's expecting an `String` object. I can substitute the value that I'm receiving but I cannot add more.

Besides that, the `headers` and `params` arrays are not being visited, which seems logical because no values are on those arrays. However, I'm not sure how I should visit those fields in the `@RequestMapping` on the method so I can insert the values picked from the class one.

What I am missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In such a case, you can override the `onEnd()` method of `AnnotationVisitor`. When invoked, you know that all values are processed and you can invoke `super.onValue()` from there before delegating to `super.onEnd()`. If you know the replacements beforehand, you can also simply leave the `onValue` method empty to drop all existing values and then repopulate the array in the end.

Comment: I've tried this and seen that `AnnotationVisitor` does not extend `JavaConstant.Visitor<T>` so there is no `onValue()` method that I can use. Do you mean `visit()`? Indeed I've been able to check that overriding `onEnd()` on the visitor returned by the `visitArray()` method allows me to add more values during `onEnd()`. However, `visitArray()` is not executed for arrays with no values - like `headers` - so I cannot add values there. Trying to add values using the `onEnd()` method on the parent `AnnotationVisitor` has thrown `AnnotationTypeMismatchException`. I am interpreting this well?

Comment: Arrays can be also visited by invoking `visit` with the entire array presented to the method. Maybe this is how it slips past you? You might just override all methods in a test to see what gets invoked.

Comment: Thanks Rafael for your help. I already tried using an array but I get the following error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: value [Ljava.lang.String;@4466af20`. If I instead use `visit` giving an String I get `AnnotationTypeMismatchException` with message `Incorrectly typed data found for annotation element public abstract java.lang.String[] [...] (Found data of type java.lang.String[example])` when trying to consume the Annotation array. About your suggestion of debugging I already checked this and only `visitArray` and `onEnd` are called on the `AnnotationVisitor`.

Comment: There must be some misuse of the visitor API. From the infromation I have, I can unfortunately not spot it. If you can create an executable reproducer, maybe I can help.

Comment: Hi Rafael. On the question there is a link to a Github repo with the example I posted. Is that enough or do you need something else? (like the differents tests I've been doing). Thanks again.

Comment: I suspect that `visitArray` is never called as the argument is a string array which is likely passed directly to `visit(String name, Object value)` where `value` contains an array of strings.

Comment: Does not happen like this. `visitArray` is called for each value (array) the visited annotation has. `visit` is not called neither is allowed to be called as the exception I describe above is thrown (`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: value [Ljava.lang.String;@4466af20`) if you try so.
If you didn't yet, could you please check the repo? It's confusing that it is not behaving as expected considering all the info you've given to me. I tried to use this with a couple different versions of bytebuddy so I don't think there is a bug on itself. I am not able where the flaw is, though.